# Computing mean per slices in Python

Tags: python, arrays, mean

I have an array :

```
A = [2,6,4,3,6,9,4,6,5]
```

Is there an elegant (1-2 lines, no loop) and pythonic way to compute the mean per blocks of 3 elements per 3 elements of A.

In order to obtain B :

```
B = [4,6,3] = [mean([2,6,4]),mean([3,6,9]),mean([4,6,5])
```

Comment: `mean([4,6,5])` is 5

Comment: What's inelegant about using a loop here?  You can avoid it by doing something like `list(map(mean,zip(*[iter(A)]*3)))`, but that's not elegant, it's the kind of "look at what I can do!" nonsense that you have to train clever beginners not to bother with.

Comment: @DSM Totally agree and deep down, `map` is also a `loop`.

Answer (score 1):

In one line it would look like this:

```
B = [sum(A[i:i+3])/3 for i in range(0, len(A), 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension, but it still includes an internal loop.

```
B = [np.mean([A[i],A[i+1],A[i+2]]) for i in np.arange(0, len(A),3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no *"elegant" way that does not use a loop*. Unless you limit your definition of *loop* to the `for` keyword. Calling `sum` or `map` for instance also uses a loop.

> *So, refuse this absurd requirement and write some clean code instead.*

```
A = [2,6,4,3,6,9,4,6,5]
n = 3

def mean(g):
  return sum(g) / len(g)

res = [mean(A[n*i:n*(i+1)]) for i in range(0, len(A)//n)]
print(res)  # -> [4.0, 6.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: @zwer is the list comprehension considered a `loop`? If yes, you might as well calculate the values in your head and literally type the result in. Is calling `sum` a loop? It definitely loops under the hood..

Comment: Just because you surround your `for..in` loop in a list comprehension structure doesn't make it any less of a loop. Now, the OP is asking for something unrealistic (even if you map an iterable it will still be performing a loop internally) but that's a whole different topic.

Comment: @zwer Refusing to comply to absurdity is decency. I will rephrase my answer to reflect your concerns though.